# Identify only full stop in the string and remove it but not decimal point

Tags: c#

The sample text : $10.00 per security. The Securities are offered at a minimum investment of100 Securities at $10.00 per Security (representing a $1,000 investment) and integral multiples of$10.00 in excess thereof 100.00%.

I should identify only the full stop and remove them but not the one in **$10.00** **100.00%** **$10.00**

So the final text will be as : $10.00 per security The Securities are offered at a minimum investment of100 Securities at $10.00 per Security (representing a $1,000 investment) and integral multiples of$10.00 in excess thereof 100.00%

text.replace(".", "") will replace all but that is not the desired output. Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Is it standard that there is always a space after the `.` ?

Comment: You may use regular expression to find those full stop not next to [0-9]

Comment: No. Space may be present or may not be. In a given text if there are more than one full stop should replace it with single at the end of the tex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) (regular expression) with:

- a *Zero-width negative **lookbehind** assertion*  - `(?<! subexpression )`
- a *Zero-width negative **lookahead** assertion* - `(?! subexpression )`

More info and examples about these assertions @ [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here's a sample implementation:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)");

        var mystring = @"$10.00 per security. The Securities are offered at a minimum investment of100 Securities at $10.00 per Security (representing a $1,000 investment) and integral multiples of$10.00 in excess thereof 100.00%.";

        var stringNoDots = regex.Replace(mystring, "");
```

Comment: @Anil, if so, please Accept the answer, as per [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)